# Get notifications from flash file in html

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am running a flash file in an html embed tag in an html file.
There is a need for me to run an action (lets say "alert") in javascript as soon as the Flash finishes.
How can I do tht

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Here is good tutorial how to do:

http://circlecube.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/as3-javascript/

If you want to fire event on the last frame, then use EnterFrame, eg:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, someFunction);
private function someFunction(e:Event):void 
{
    if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, someFunction);
        //fire some externalinterface event
    }
}
```

Comment: I have gone over both the package and the example and couldn't find a callback for when the flash finishes running